# Running an Ant script to prepare a Database in Bluemix

Tags: ant, ibm-cloud

I have an Ant script that I use to populate/prepare a database. All I need is to set the host, port and credentials for the database. It works fine for MySQL and DB2, the DB just need to be reachable from were the script is executed.
The DB service in Bluemix gives me a DB with an IP (75.x.x.x) that is only reachable from the internal network of Bluemix, it is not accessible externally.

My understanding is that my ant script needs to be executed from inside the Bluemix network/servers.

How can I do that?

What would be the alternatives?

I'm considering to create a NodeJS script to trigger that ant internally, but I'm not sure if it will work properly.

Comment: An ip address of 75.x.x.x is reachable on the public Internet.

Comment: Yes, it is. I think in past it used to be 10.x.x.x, but also I thought it had all ports blocked intentionally. Anyway, I'm setting a new environment to try again following the doc in the answer from CharlesL.

Answer (score 3):

dashDB always had the ability for local clients (outside of Bluemix) to connect to the cloud database, and SQL Database later added the feature as well. So you should be able to populate a database as long as you have the correct driver client installed on your local machine.

Can you provide more details on how you tested that the IP is not reachable? Is there a firewall put in place between your local machine and Bluemix? Note that ping is not a good test because the port is blocked for security reasons. You may try the JDBC port indicated on the connection page from the console.

See link for instructions on how to make a connection:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SQLDB/index.html#connecting-to-sqldb

Comment: I tested several months ago, don't remember what was exactly the problem. Ping indeed doesn't work. I'll try to follow your link

Comment: Yes, you are right that SQLDB was not accessible a few months ago. Please try again and see if you can access it now from outside.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a simple custom buildpack. You can start with a sample like this one:

https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-test-buildpack

fork it and modify the `bin/compile` script to run your ant task instead. Then put your ant script (and probably executable as I expect it is not installed in the Bluemix environment) in a directory and run

```
cf push <appname> -b <your forked git url>
```

To push it to Bluemix and run it. If you're just using it once you can probably get away with hard-coding the address and credentials, or else you can bind  to the same service instance and get the info from `VCAP_SERVICES`.